Jackson serialize superclass properties as nested element of child object?
I'm trying to align some json streaming from XSD-derived classes in a way that is protobuf-friendly.
The XDSs have been created using  elements, which derive as superclass/child classes.
The Protobuf equivalent has been defined using contained 'base' elements to store the common properties (so each child contains a 'base' property that is the common class).
The imported XSD creates:
public class Vehicle {
  string make;
  string model;
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
  integer doors;
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
  integer weight
}

Is there a way I can get the Car class to serialise to json with the Vehicle superclass properties wrapped as:
{
  "base": {"make":"Ford", "model":"Ka"},
  "doors": 2
}

I.e. as if the Car class had been defined as:
public class Car {
  Vehicle base;
  integer doors;
}

I get a large (and evolving) object model, but relatively few base classes, so I'd be OK to annotate or write custom serializers for the base classes, but it would be unworkable to have to change every child class.
